# How to find value in string array using JSONPath?

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

I am trying to filter a list of formParagraph objects where the hasContent property is true and the legalStatutes string array contains a string with 'AIA'.  issue is that 'AIA' is not always in zero position in the array.

The below JSONPath only works if 'AIA' is first item in array.

```
   $.businessResponse.formParagraphList[ ? ((@.hasContent == true) && (@.legalStatutes[0] == 'AIA'))] {
    "rbacUser": null,
    "businessResponse": {
        "formParagraphList": [{
                "id": 1261,
                "hasContent": true,
                "legalStatutes": [
                    "Pre_AIA",
                    "AIA"
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 67,
                "hasContent": true,
                "legalStatutes": [
                    "AIA",
                    "Pre_AIA"
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 68,
                "hasContent": true,
                "legalStatutes": [
                    "Pre_AIA"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there a way to check for the existence of a specific string in a string array within a JSON object without knowing it's index using JSONPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, figured out a solution to my problem.  Used the `.indexOf()` method to check if the string exists in the array.

```
$.businessResponse.formParagraphList[?((@.hasContent==true) && (@.legalStatutes.indexOf('AIA') > -1))]
```

**UPDATE:**
The above JSONPath is valid in online evaluators, but it didn't work in Newtonsoft for C#.  here is what I got to work with this library.

```
$.businessResponse.formParagraphList[?(@.hasExaminerNote==true && @.legalStatutes[*]=='Pre_AIA')]
```

Comment: One note, this doesn't work using newtonsoft in c#.  will post that answer when I find it